# Conteo distintivo del mismo campo en diferentes tablas

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de contar todos los registros del campo DNI que hay en tres tablas de meses diferentes pero NO quiero contar los DNI que ya se contaron en la tabla anterior. Es decir, quiero  meterle un DISTINCT entre tablas para que en el conteo total de DNIs no se repita ninguno.
La query que hice, es esta:

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS total 
FROM 
    (select COUNT(DISTINCT a.dni) AS count
     FROM dni_202210 a
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.dni) AS count
     FROM dni_202211 b
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.dni) AS count
     FROM dni_202212 c
    ) AS t;
```

Agradezco cualquier idea. Buen dia!

Comment: A ver si entendí, queres unir todos los registro de todas las tablas (_como si todos estuvieran en una sola_) y del resultado obtener con `DISTINCT` la cantidad de DNIs, correcto? PD: Si es esto, creo que ya te di una pista de como obtener la respuesta.

Comment: No sumes la union de los conteos, sino *cuenta* de las uniones (sin `ALL`). ¿El dni se repite en cada tabla?.

Comment: Hola Marcos, efectivamente, quiero contar el numero total de DNIs que hay entre las tres tablas (la de octubre, noviembre y diciembre, todas las tablas con las mismas columnas), pero si cuento un DNI determinado en octubre, no quiero volver a contarlo ni en noviembre ni en diciembre.

Comment: Hola Sal, un DNI puede repetirse o no en las otras dos tablas. Es decir, un dni puede solo estar en la tabla de octubre o podría estar en octubre y noviembre, o podría estar en octubre, noviembre y diciembre. Si tuviera una sola tabla con los dni de los tres meses juntos, haria un SELECT count(distinct dni). Sin embargo, esto quiero hacerlo de una vez en 3 tablas diferentes tal y como expliqué anteriormente

Comment: " Si tuviera una sola tabla con los dni de los tres meses juntos, haria un SELECT count(distinct dni).".. justamente, sabes la solucion.. uni las 3 tablas planas, como estan, y despues hace el count ;)